# showing people command line programs

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

Hello I am running ubuntu mate. My question has to do with command line programs. I am wondering if their is a way that I can have someone on any operating system see and use the command line interface. I am wanting to do this to market or show someone the program to see if they like it. Nowadays programs like microft word are streamed instead of buying the package. Any Ideas?

Comment: You can try the Ubuntu command line at:.    https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/